# Why Didn't I Obtain The Mars Nav Segment From The Vor's Prize Quest?

Tags: warframe

I've defeated Vor in the assassination mission and completed the Vor's Prize Quest. After defeating Vor, I obtained the Venus nav segment, but not the Mars nav segment. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Pre U19: unlike any other bosses, Vor gives 2 nav segments. You should have gotten both Venus and Mars after defeating him. For some reason you don't install both at the same time, however. Install the first one, do a mission on that node, and come back to your ship. Exit navigation and you should be able to insert the nav segment.

Post U19: Planets are now unlocked by completing new nodes between planets called "junctions," as per starchart 3.0.  Each junction has certain criteria for you to meet before it will let you attempt to clear it.